# Javascript json eval() injection

Tags: javascript, json, eval, code-injection

I am making an AJAX chat room with the guidance of an AJAX book teaching me to use JSON and eval() function.
This chat room has normal chat function and a whiteboard feature.
When a normal text message comes from the php server in JSON format, the javascript in browser does this:

Without Whiteboard Command -------------------------------------------

```
function importServerNewMessagesSince(msgid) {
    //loadText() is going to return me a JSON object from the server
    //it is an array of {id, author, message}
    var latest = loadText("get_messages_since.php?message=" + msgid);
    var msgs = eval(latest);
    for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    var msg = msgs[i];
                    displayMessage(escape(msg.id), escape(msg.author), escape(msg.contents));
    }   ...
```

---

The whiteboard drawing commands are sent by server in JSON format with special user name called "SVR_CMD", now the javascript is changed slightly:

With Whiteboard Command --------------------------------------------------

```
function importServerNewMessagesSince(msgid) {
    //loadText() is going to return me a JSON object from the server
    //it is an array of {id, author, message}
    var latest = loadText("get_messages_since.php?message=" + msgid);
    var msgs = eval(latest);
    for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    var msg = msgs[i];
                    if (msg.author == "SVR_CMD") {

                        eval(msg.contents);  // <-- Problem here ...

                         //I have a javascript drawLine() function to handle the whiteboard drawing
                        //server command sends JSON function call like this: 
                        //"drawLine(200,345,222,333)" eval() is going to parse execute it
                        //It is a hacker invitation to use eval() as someone in chat room can
                        //insert a piece of javascript code and send it using the name SVR_CMD?

                   else {
                        displayMessage(escape(msg.id), escape(msg.author), escape(msg.contents));
                    }

    }   ...
```

---

Now, if the hacker changes his username to SVR_CMD in the script, then in the message input start typing javascript code, insdead of drawLine(200,345,222,333), he is injecting redirectToMyVirusSite(). eval() will just run it for him in everyone's browser in the chat room.
So, as you can see, to let the eval to execute a command from an other client in the chat room is obviously a hacker invitation. I understand the book I followed is only meant to be an introduction to the functions. How do we do it properly with JSON in a real situation?

e.g. is there a server side php or .net function to javascriptencode/escape to make sure no hacker can send a valid piece of javascript code to other client's browser to be eval() ? Or is it safe to use JSON eval() at all, it seems to be a powerful but evil function?

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: That's what I hate about web development books. They can't change with the web. `eval()` = evil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is this book? `eval` is evil, there is not a single reason to use it, ever.

To transform a JSON string into a javascript object, you can do the following:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(latest)
```

Which means you can then use:

```
[].forEach.call(obj, function( o ) {
    // You can use o.message, o.author, etc.
} )
```

To do the opposite (javascript object -> JSON string), the following works:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Comment: According to Angus Croll, JSON.parse uses eval() itself. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: @Goose yes, `eval` has usages. (This answer is 3 years old, I used to be adamant about things.) However, I'd still recommend to not ever use it. An experienced programmer will recognize that the use cases are very limited, and will know that in programming, dogmas don't solve problems :). Also, `JSON.parse` in modern browsers doesn't use `eval`. See e.g. v8 source: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/json-parser.h#93

Comment: @Goose another thing: instead of quoting someone else, you could've just looked at the source. [Here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for Crockford, [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/parseJSON.js) for jQuery. Which shows that jQuery doesn't do `eval` anymore, by the way. (i.e. your article is old.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think to check sources. I will try in the future. It makes sense that JSON/modern browsers would move away from eval.

Answer (score 3):

It only is unsafe if the executed code is generated by other clients and not by the server. Of course you would need to prevent anybody to use that name, though I don't understand why you would use the "author" field? Just send an object `{"whiteboard":"drawLine(x,y,z)"}` instead of `{"author":"SVR_CMD","contents":"drawLine(x,y,z)"}`.

But it is right, eval() is still an invitation for hackers. One can always send invalid data and try to influence the output more or less directly. The only way for escaping is a proper serialisation of the data you want to receive and send - the drawings data. How do you receive the whiteboard commands? There is no serverside "escape" function to make javascript code "clean" - it would always be a security hole.

I would expect a serialisation like

```
message = {
    "author": "...", // carry the information /who/ draws
    "whiteboard": {
         "drawline": [200, 345, 222, 333]
    }
}
```

so you can sanitize the commands (here: "drawline") easiliy.

The use of `eval()` might be OK if you have very complex commands and want to reduce the transferred data by building them serverside. Still, you need to parse and escape the received commands from other clients properly. But I'd recommend to find a solution without eval.

Comment: 1. the code reuses the importServerNewMessagesSince() function and treats author=svr_cmd as a special user where the 'contents' field has javascript command. 2. it receives the whiteboard commands drawLine(x,y,z,w) in the 'contents' field where drawLine() is a javascript function in the webpage. eval("drawLine(x,y,z,w)") will then execute the function directly.

Comment: No, the question was "how does the server receive the command to draw a line?". If the server receives a javascript code string, this is not only an invitation to hack your tool, it would be a gaping wide open door!

Answer (score 1):

Setting eval issue aside, do not use field that can be filled by user - `.author` in your code  - for authentication purposes. Add another field to your JSON message, say `.is_server_command` that when present, would signify special treating of message. This field is will be not depended on user input and thus wouldn't be hijacked by "hacker".

Comment: author is the the "display name" of the user. For who typed the message and/or who draw the picture on whiteboard. I copied and pasted it from the book. Only wanted to make the core working then come to the membership stuff. I am new to json. The eval() function in the copied code caught my attention. So I made a post on that.

Comment: Yes. Exactly because USER decides what will go in this field, you CAN'T use it for stuff that supposed to be decided only by your server.

Comment: The "special" user name can be SVR_CMD, it can be "34ee52aa3457ff" or any token. When a whiteboard draw command is issued, this id will be exposed to anyone who open up to view the source code. So a hacker can always copy that token and mimic a server command. My point is, the problem seems to be eval() being too powerful and can execute a piece of code from user injection.

Comment: If you use another field that can only be generated by server and is not affected by user input, then you'll avoid this problem. eval is powerful, but if it is called only when sanctioned by server with carefully server generated data, it can be quite safe.